# Variable values update before I give that instruction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I apologize in advance for this way to long post.
I'm working on a C# function to unify a mesh's triangles'orientation for a Unity3D project. I use `Vector3` type, which is a struct composed by a `float array [3]`.

In order to do so I take a first triangle and check if it points outwark or inward. After that I check for an adiacent one and check the order of the indices of the triangle. If I find couple of indices in order, I flip them.
here an example:

- base triangle' indices: `1 2 3`
- second triangle' indices:

  - `1 2 4` (`1 2` are in the same order as the base triangle, need to flip to `2 1 4`)
  - `4 2 1` (`2 1` are not in the same order, then do nothing)

The check returns me the next triangle to check if it finds; otherwise it returns a null vector. 
if "next" isn't null I make the "next" triangle to "current", I store the fixed triangle in a variable, in order to avoid the program to keep checking the same indices and re-iterate the check.

The problem is that some variable seem to update their values before the instruction messing up my conditions.

As you can see in the code below I have a really complex If statement that tries to find if two triangles'indices are present in the same order (not necessary the same position) like:

```
1 2 3 (base)
```

all the following possible result need to be flipped to

```
1 2 4 -> 2 1 4
4 1 2 -> 1 4 2
2 4 1 -> 4 2 1
```

that minus before `mesh.Index[]` is needed because it seems to use `IndexList` values, instead of `mesh.Index` ones and I don't know why.

I'm using this custom struct to test the program outside Unity

```
public struct SimplifiedMesh
{
    //this stores the order of the vertices needed to 
    //create all the triangles of the mesh.
    public int[] Index; 
    it list all the vertices of the mesh
    public Vector3[] Vertex;
};
```

`IndexList` is used to store the checked triangles. At first all values are positive, but when it check one, it turns its indices negative.

```
int[] IndexList = new int[Unimesh.Index.Length]; IndexList = Unimesh.Index;
```

First I check with a different method in order to determine if the face is pointing outward or inward

```
FirstCheck(Unimesh, CentreofMesh, currentIndices);

//this will tell the program this triad is already checked
IndexList[currentIndices[0]] *= -1;
IndexList[currentIndices[0] + 1] *= -1;
IndexList[currentIndices[0] + 2] *= -1;
```

The following now is the tough part. Here a legend of variables:

- `currentIndices` is an `Array[3]` storing the position of thr three indices of the last checked triangle in the `mesh.Index` array. It's used to find an adiacent one;
- `next` is the return variable that return the next vector to be considered for the check or null if he has found no adiacent triangles.
- `mesh.Index[currentIndices[0-1-2]` are the current indices
- `FlipNormals` get the mesh indices, go to the three indices pointed by "Flipvector" and swap the first two, inverting their order

and here the code

```
static int[] AdiacentFace(SimplifiedMesh mesh, int[] IndexList, int[] currentIndices)
{
    int[] next = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < IndexList.Length; i += 3)
    {
        if (IndexList[i] > 0 || IndexList[i + 1] > 0)
        {
            if
              // e restituisce la nuova terna modificata
                ((IndexList[i] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[0]] && (IndexList[i + 1] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[1]] || IndexList[i + 2] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[2]])) ||
                (IndexList[i + 1] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[0]] && (IndexList[i + 2] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[1]] || IndexList[i] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[2]])) ||
                (IndexList[i + 2] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[0]] && (IndexList[i] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[1]] || IndexList[i + 1] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[2]])))
            {
                int[] Flipvector = new int[3];
                Flipvector[0] = mesh.Index[i];
                Flipvector[1] = mesh.Index[i+1];
                Flipvector[2] = mesh.Index[i + 2];
                FlipNormals(mesh, Flipvector);
                // Elimina la terna per i successivi controlli
                IndexList[i] *= -1;
                IndexList[i + 1] *= -1;
                IndexList[i + 2] *= -1;
                // Ritorna gli indici del nuovo vettore
                next[0] = i;
                next[1] = i + 1;
                next[2] = i + 2;
                return next;
            }
            else if
            ((IndexList[i] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[0]] && (IndexList[i + 2] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[1]] || IndexList[i + 1] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[2]])) ||
            (IndexList[i + 1] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[0]] && (IndexList[i] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[1]] || IndexList[i + 2] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[2]])) ||
            (IndexList[i + 2] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[0]] && (IndexList[i + 1] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[1]] || IndexList[i] == -mesh.Index[currentIndices[2]])))
            {
                // Elimina la terna per i successivi controlli
                IndexList[i] *= -1;
                IndexList[i + 1] *= -1;
                IndexList[i + 2] *= -1;
                // Ritorna gli indici del nuovo vettore
                next[0] = i;
                next[1] = i + 1;
                next[2] = i + 2;
                return next;
            }
        }
    }
    next = null;
    return next;
}
```

Comment: The value isn't magically changing - you are almost certainly updating it without realising. I'd suggest debugging, line by line. After each line ask yourself 'what state do I expect things to be in, and why'. Is the app in that state? If not, you have found your bug.

Comment: @mkwills
I tries to dibug
'code IndexList[currentIndices[0]] *= -1; '
changes the value the IndexList but also the Unimesh.Index

Comment: What is the type of `Unimesh`? Of `Unimesh.Index`?

Comment: @mjwills its type is the struct I created.
Anyway I found out the problems. Since I'm a beginner with C#, I didn't know the operation "IndexList = Unimesh.Index" between arrays pass the reference, instead of the single values, thus updating IndexList's values, update the Unimesh.Index'ones.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I'm a beginner with C#, and I didn't know the operation "IndexList = Unimesh.Index" between arrays pass the reference, instead of the single values.
I managed to solve the problem in this way.
From:

```
int[] IndexList = new int[Unimesh.Index.Length]; Indexlist = Unimesh.Index;
```

to:

```
int[] IndexList = new int[Unimesh.Index.Length];
For (int i = 0; i < Unimesh.Index.Length; i++)
    {
    IndexList[i] = Unimesh.Index[i];
    }
```

This way I copy just the values and not the reference to the array.